# Error installing rails 4 in mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

I am trying to set up rails in my mac(Yosemite) machine. But when I do

```
gem install rails
```

I get the following error. Please help.

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/Paa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/bin/ruby extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make  clean

make
compiling generator.c
make: /usr/local/opt/gcc46/bin/gcc-4.6: No such file or directory
make: *** [generator.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/Paa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/json-1.8.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/Paa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/1.9.1/json-1.8.2/gem_make.out
```

What am I missing here.??

Comment: Xcode command line tools?

Comment: @7stud xcode-select --install
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates

Comment: The error here: `make: /usr/local/opt/gcc46/bin/gcc-4.6: No such file or directory` says that the rubygems system is trying to compile some files with a compiler located at `/usr/local/opt/gcc46/bin/gcc-4.6`, but there is no compiler there.  I don't know where rubygems got that path from.

Answer (score 1):

I think rvm might be trying to use gcc 4.6,  [which doesn't work properly with rvm](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/pull/3097).  I believe you can:

1. Uninstall gcc 4.6 (`brew rm gcc46`)
2. Pull the latest rvm (`rvm get stable`)
3. Retry `gem install rails`